# Onchange select without refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

When change value my page is refresh because i have to send value to query data
but my selector doesn't show value when selected

```
<form name='active' action='' method='GET'>
<select class="form-control" id="section" name="section" onchange="list()" >
<option value="0"> - - Select All - - </option>
  <?php
       $section = $db->fetch();
       foreach ($section as $key => $v) {
        $section_name = $v['section'];
        echo "<option value='".$section_name."'>",$section_name,"</option>";
       }
?>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function list(){ 
      document.active.submit(); 
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Well the page is refreshed, so the values are gonne turn back to default

Comment: Yes. but in selector should be selected

Comment: Put `event.preventDefault()` on start of this function `list()`...

Comment: I put event.preventDefault() but it dose not work.

Comment: do you save the submitted value in your database ?

Comment: No. I don't save value in my database but It's select from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an option in a  dropdown other than the first one to be selected on page load, you have to add the `selected="selected"` attribute to one of the `<option>` elements like so :

```
<select class="form-control" id="section" name="section" onchange="list()" >
  <option value="0"> - - Select All - - </option>
  <option value="1" selected="selected"> I'm selected </option>
  <option value="2"> I'm not selected </option>
</select>
```

In your case, it implies checking either the GET variable or the database value in your foreach loop to set the attribute accordingly.